# Writing in a binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

My program scans names and birth years and stores them in an array of structures. Scanning from keyboard and printing in screen works fine, but I'm not sure whether printing in my binary file is correct because my program runs without errors and I can't check if the data has been printed correctly in the binary file.
My question is about whether the syntax of my "fwrite" functions is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNAME 50 //size of name
#define MAXPERSONS 2 //Max num of persons

typedef struct{
    char name[MAXNAME];
    int year;
}person_t;

int read_person(person_t[], int);//scans the person
int write_person(const person_t[], int, FILE*);//prints the persons in the screen and the bfile

int main()
{
    FILE *pfile;
    person_t v[3];
    int iscan=0,iprint;

    if((pfile=fopen("persons.bin","wb"))==NULL) printf("couldnt open<vehicles.txt>\n");

    else{
        while(iscan<MAXPERSONS){
            read_person(&v[iscan],iscan+1);
            iscan++;
        }
        for(iprint=0;iprint<iscan;iprint++)
            write_person(&v[iprint],iprint+1,pfile);
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int read_person(person_t v[],int i)
{
    printf("Person %d",i);
    printf("\n\tName: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(v->name);
    printf("\n\tYear: ");
    scanf("%d",&v->year);
}

int write_person(const person_t v[],int j, FILE *pfile)
{
    //print in screen
    printf("\nPerson %d",j);
    printf("\n\tName: %s\n",v->name);
    printf("\n\tYear: %d\n",v->year);

    //print in the binary file
    fwrite(v->name,sizeof(char),1,pfile);
    fwrite(&v->year,sizeof(int),1,pfile);
}
```

This program reads from the bin file

```
    #include<stdio.h>

#define MAXNAME 50 //size of name
#define MAXPERSONS 2 //Max num of persons

typedef struct{
    char name[MAXNAME];
    int year;
}person_t;

int read_person(person_t[], int, FILE*);
int write_person(const person_t[], int);
int main(){
    FILE *pfile;
    person_t v[3];
    int iscan=0,iprint;

    if((pfile=fopen("persons.bin","rb"))==NULL) printf("couldnt open<vehicles.txt>\n");

    else{
        while(iscan<MAXPERSONS){
        read_person(&v[iscan],iscan+1,pfile);
        iscan++;
        }
        for(iprint=0;iprint<iscan;iprint++)
            write_person(&v[iprint],iprint+1);
    }
fclose(pfile);
printf("\n\n"); 
return 0;   
}
int read_person(person_t v[],int i, FILE *pfile){
    //read from the binary file
    fread(v->name, sizeof(v->name),1,pfile);
    fread(&v->year,sizeof(v->year),1,pfile);
}
int write_person(const person_t v[],int j){
    //print in screen
     printf("\nPerson %d",j); 
        printf("\n\tName: %s\n",v->name);  
        printf("\n\tYear: %d\n",v->year);           
}
```

Comment: you write just one char with fwrite.

Comment: @zubergu Could you please tell me what would be the correct syntax of the fwrite functions in my program?

Comment: side note: both `read_person` and `write_person` are defined to return `int` but in-fact return *nothing*. Also, `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard conforming. In fact, unless the most recent stream activity on the given stream was *output*, the results are *undefined*. Finally, `gets()` is so evil it has been deprecated from the standard library and will be removed in the next version. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest changing `fwite()` to write the full size of `person_t`.

```
int write_person(const person_t v[], int j, FILE *pfile) {
  //print in screen
  printf("\nPerson %d",j);
  printf("\n\tName: %s\n",v[j].name);
  printf("\n\tYear: %d\n",v[j].year);

  //print in the binary file
  if (1 != fwrite(&v[j], sizeof(v[j]),1, pfile)) handle_error();
  return 0;
}

int read_person(person_t v[], int i) {
  printf("Person %d",i);
  printf("\n\tName: ");
  //  don't do this fflush(stdin);
  // consider scanf() gets(v.name);
  // " %49[^\n]": space to consume leading whitespace, 49 (50 -1 ) limit input, [^\n] to read any text but \n
  if (1 != scanf(" %49[\n]", v[i].name)) handle_error();
  printf("\n\tYear: ");
  if (1 != scanf("%d",&v[i].year)) handle_error();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seem to be working, my other program that reads from the bin file prints garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing and reading the entire person_t struct.

```
int write_person(const person_t v[],int j, FILE *pfile)
{
    //print in screen
    printf("\nPerson %d",j);
    printf("\n\tName: %s\n",v[j].name);
    printf("\n\tYear: %d\n",v[j].year);
    fwrite(&(v[j]),sizeof(person_t),1,pfile);
}
```

The general idea you are approaching is called 'serialization' or 'marshalling' (depending upon author).  There are many ways serialize or marshall data, but some good approaches are JSON, UBJSON, MessagePack, and ProtocolBuffers, among others.